# C# Socket exception when Shutdown in called on the client

Tags: c#, sockets

I am writing a C# client to connect with an embedded system (server). Initially i am able to connect to the server and send data. Then i reboot the server (with the client not being shutdown) and on the server coming to ready state, I first try to disconnect (shutdown) client and reconnect the same. Now during client shutdown i am getting the socket exception 10053 - An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

Can you help me in understanding what could be the issue?
Note: if i try to reconnect without trying to shutdown (after the server reboot) then the connect is working fine and i am able to transmit data.

Answer (score 0):

The socket probably uses a TCP protocol. TCP is designed to keep a constant line of communication between the two. This means that in order to close the connection, both client and server say to each other that the connection will be ended. But as you only get the error after a restart I believe that when you shutdown the server, the server did not get a chance to properly shut down the connection too. So, when trying to restart the connection on the client, it already 'lost' its connection without knowing it as it didn't hear it from the server. Thus, it cannot officially close the socket as the server does not communicate to the socket anymore.

You have two options: accept the exception and use a try catch, which might be less neat. The other option is to try and force the server to officially close the socket before or during shutdown, so that the client is informed. Then, the client will retry starting a connection every few minutes.

I can't go into specifics as I haven't worked much with the code yet, but I hope this seems clear to you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).